# In iOS 9 the uitableview footer text alignment/spacing changed, what can I do?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios9, footer

Hei.

These two pictures below show what changed. Here's my code for it and the code didn't change.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 0) {
    return @"If enabled, closing apps via the app switcher won't actually close the app itself.\n\nThis option is perfect to use with Fast Freeze.";
  }

  NSString *offDescription = @"OFF\nDisables the backgrounding capability completely. The app has to restart every time you close it.";
  NSString *fastFreezeDescription = @"FAST FREEZE\nThis mode is similar to what 'Smart Close' by rpetrich did. Usually an app has up to 10 minutes to perform tasks in the background before it gets suspended in memory. Since this can be an unnecessary battery drain, Fast Freeze will suspend the app right after you close it.";
  NSString *nativeDescription = @"NATIVE\nThis is Apple's built in way of backgrounding.";
  NSString *unlimitedNativeDescription = @"UNLIMITED NATIVE\nThis background mode allows apps to execute background tasks for an unlimited period of time, so the app won't get suspended in memory after 10 minutes.";
  NSString *foregroundDescription = @"FOREGROUND\nForeground tricks the system into thinking that the app wasn't closed and is still running in foreground. This is the perfect way to continue to listen to internet streams or videos while using another app.";

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n\n%@\n\n%@\n\n%@\n\n%@", offDescription, fastFreezeDescription, nativeDescription, unlimitedNativeDescription, foregroundDescription];
}
```

Here are the screenshots:

[image: before]

This is the view before (iOS 8), notice that "\nOFF\nDisables ..." has the gap to the last UITableViewCell like it should be.

[image: after]

This is the view after (iOS 9), the gap is off. Too much space there.

So, does anyone know why this happens? If anyone has an fix or something, please tell me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you configure estimated heights?

Comment: No, I didn' do that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an Apple's bug (iOS 9.0 - 9.1), the more lines footer has, the bigger misplacement gets.

You can even reproduce this in the storyboard using static table view.

[image: storyboard-bug]

I cound't find any workaround yet, the best advice I can give is to [file a bug report to Apple.](http://bugreport.apple.com)

---

### Update

The bug in storyboard seems to be fixed in Xcode 7.2 beta 2. However this issue still persists when you run the app even on iOS 9.2 simulator.

---

### Update 2

Narrowed down the reproduction of this bug. Basically something breaks after your app presents a table view section header. Check [this repo](https://github.com/nkukushkin/Table-Footer-Bug-Tester) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems like iOS 9 does a great job being more stable in general as they announced it. :p

Comment: I think I've found the point in API that causes this bug, check the second update. This bug is very upsetting.

Comment: Alright, good to know. Please also let me know in case you find a fix.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in iOS 10 beta 2.